# differentiation of a surface

Tags: derivatives

> Consider the surface $\{\left(x,y,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid z=f\left(x,y\right)\}$ with $f(x,y) = x^3 + 2xy + y$.
>
> Show, using the definition of differentiability, that $f$ is differentiable at any point $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So I used the standard definition of differentiability

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(x+h,y+k) - f(x, y) - Df(a)(h)}{||h||}$$
and I got

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{3h^2x + h^3 + 2hk}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}}$$

What could I do from here? I really don't know how to do the last step (assuming it's right) and get differentiability. Anybody who could help me out?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: @Narasimham please try to make edits wich also improve readability.

Comment: Why are you vandalizing your post? The closing `}` is needed for the MathJax markup to correctly parse.

Answer (score 1):

For all $\left(h,k\right)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, we have
$$f\left(x+h,y+k\right)
=x^3+3x^2h+3xh^2+h^3+2xy+2xk+2hy+2hk+y+k$$
$$=f\left(x,y\right)+\ell_{x,y}\left(h,k\right)+\mathcal{R}_{x,y}\left(h,k\right)$$
where $\ell_{x,y}\left(h,k\right)=3x^2h+2xk+2hy+h$ and $\mathcal{R}_{x,y}\left(h,k\right)=3xh^2+h^3+2hk$.

So $f$ is differentiable at $\left(x,y\right)$ iff by definition $\ell_{x,y}$ is a bounded linear map and $\mathcal{R}_{x,y}\left(h,k\right)=o\left(\|\left(h,k\right)\|\right)$ (and then the differential of $f$ at $\left(x,y\right)$ in the direction $\left(h,k\right)$ will be $\ell_{x,y}\left(h,k\right)$).

It is obvious that $\ell_{x,y}$ is a bounded linear map (we just need the linearity in finite dimension), and as for the rest, we have
$$|\mathcal{R}_{x,y}\left(h,k\right)|\leq3|x|h^2+|h|h^2+2|h||k|\leq\left(3|x|+|h|+1\right)\left(h^2+k^2\right)$$
where we used the majoration $|h|,|h||k|\leq\left(h^2+k^2\right)$. Hence the have
$$\frac{|\mathcal{R}_{x,y}\left(h,k\right)|}{\|\left(h,k\right)\|}\leq\left(3|x|+|h|+1\right)\sqrt{h^2+k^2}=C\|\left(h,k\right)\|\longrightarrow0$$
when $\|\left(h,k\right)\|\rightarrow0$.

Some comments : in your post, you talk about a surface defined with $f$, but your true question is the calculation of the differential of $f$, so it is useless to mention the surface. Another thing : take care of your limit : it is the norm $\|\left(h,k\right)\|$ which tends to zero, not only $h$.

Comment: This is over my head I'm afraid. A superb answer, without question, but uses material I haven't yet covered. Thanks a lot for the answer, but would it be possible to simplify it? Isn't it possible to use just the standard definition, for us laymen out there?

Comment: Actually, what I wrote is EXACTLY what you wrote : with my notations we have $$\frac{f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)-\ell_{x,y}(h,k)}{\|(h,k)\|}\rightarrow0$$ when $\|(h,k)\|\rightarrow0$. What I've noted $\ell_{x,y}$ is the differential of $f$ at the point $(x,y)$ (you noted this linear map $Df((x,y))$). But if I'm not wrong, your true question was to compute the limit, what I did : $\mathcal{R}_{x,y}(h,k)=f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)-\ell_{x,y}(h,k)\rightarrow0$. You can use the majorations I wrote.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the clarification, I understand the way you wrote it up now. It's very clear now actually, so thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Ask me if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the same variable name twice ($h$ is both a vector with components $(h,k)$ and a component of said vector). Also, the proper definition of a derivative is
$$Df(x)[v] = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+hv) - f(x)}{h}$$
where $x = (x_1,x_2)$ and $v=(v_1,v_2) \in \mathbb R^2$. For the (total) derivative to exist, this must be a linear form in $v$, i.e. $Df(x)[v] = g(x)^T v$ where $g: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is called the gradient of $f$, denoted by $g(x) = \nabla f(x) = \pmatrix{\frac\partial{\partial x_1} f(x)\\ \frac\partial{\partial x_2}f(x)}$.